# image data as source in gstreamer

Tags: c++, c, gstreamer

I want to make a GStreamer application which takes image data as source instead of a file location. My intention is to display image received through tcp. When tcp got an image data(byte array) it should pass the data to the gstreamer plugin directly with out saving it locally.

Comment: It's not very clear what is your question. Have you tried anything? What problems you encountered?

Comment: My intention is to give image byte array directly to the gstreamer  source instead image location. sorry for the unclear question.

Comment: Please edit you question: add more details, some example or use case. I will vote for reopen and will be glad to answer.

Comment: Btw, I think `appsrc` element is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The multifilesrc should do the work.

> Description
>
> Reads buffers from sequentially named files. If used together with an
>   image decoder, one needs to use the "caps" property or a capsfilter to
>   force to caps containing a framerate. Otherwise image decoders send
>   EOS after the first picture. We also need a videorate element to set
>   timestamps on all buffers after the first one in accordance with the
>   framerate.
>
> File names are created by replacing "%d" with the index using
>   printf().
>
> Example launch line
>
> ```
> gst-launch-1.0 multifilesrc location="img.%04d.png" index=0 caps="image/png,framerate=\(fraction\)12/1" ! \
>     pngdec ! videoconvert ! videorate ! theoraenc ! oggmux ! \
>     filesink location="images.ogg"
> ```
>
> This pipeline creates a video file "images.ogg" by joining multiple
>   PNG files named img.0000.png, img.0001.png, etc.

Source : http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-multifilesrc.html

So if your using gstreamer by the command line this should do the trick.
You just need to speficiy the file and "loop" on the file when its received.

Otherwise it's not so complicated to code a gstreamer pipeline that use a multifilesrc as source.

Comment: thank you for the answer...  can i give a byte array instead of image location