# Gstreamer video sink from Binary image data using Gstreamer

Tags: jpeg, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

The Question is similar to what is asked in [image data as source in gstreamer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22625117/image-data-as-source-in-gstreamer)

Here is what my requirement : 
 
1. There is a binary file[consider it as any extension] which contains multiple image data [say 10 image data in one binary file] 
 
2. The binary file is extracted and the image data(s) are saved to a folder location in windows as .jpg 
 
3. For video display I used the below pipeline 
gst-launch-1.0 multifilesrc location=":/Images/%d.jpg" caps="image/jpeg,framerate=10/5" ! jpegdec ! autovideosink 
          ******* Under Images folder, there are .jpg files stored with names starting from 1.jpg, 2.jpg etc.. . The %d would take the images from the path starting index from 1 to the highest count of value [continuously numbered images]*

Everything looks fine till here. Now the requirement is to skip the step #2, i.e we don't need to convert the image binary data to be stored in a physical drive path as image files. Instead, we are looking for something like passing the binary data that is extracted from the binary file directly as a source pad to the GStreamer pipeline. Is this possible ? If so, how should I write the source pad for the pipeline ?

Reason : There are as much as 32 GB data in the binary file [these are webcam images compressed in binary file ], so saving these data again to image format is another 32 GB space required in the drive [and this goes on and on]. Since we already have the image data in binary format, we need a mechanism to pass these binary data [in the form of buffer in C programming] directly to GStreamer pipeline source.

Note : gstreamer 1.0 is used in windows OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First question would be why you are not saving video data in a video file format - for that exact purpose..

You can write a GStreamer application with an `appsrc`. You would then have to parse the data as you do in step 2) in your application and feed the image chunks via `appsrc` to the `jpegdec`.

Comment: exactly the same question. 32GB worth of images and then you stream it into video. Why not save it in video format itself?

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. So let me make this more clear on the data part. 32 GB of data is from a different source [from a surveillance camera]. By saying 32 GB, that is the maximum data that is available in a memory card. So basically we are just trying to extract the images that are available in the memory card to display it in video format. To answer your Why not video data because there is limitation for the device to capture video data in memory card.

Comment: @Florian,Zwoch, I also came across appsrc, need to dig further to understand the concept as I am not very familiar with gstreamers.And yeah I have already parsed the file using file objects and I have the image data as binary array. So, is it possible to send chunks of binary data to appsrc like in a loop ??

Comment: You basically wrap your data chunk into a GstBuffer object and push it via the appsrc api into the pipeline. You will need to decide if you want to run the appsrc into push or pull mode.. but once you read the docs on it you should know what to do.

Comment: I will accept the answer by @Florian Zwoch, however I have not yet implemented it. Going through the Gstreamer appsrc documentation, I find this could be what I am looking for [push/pull mode using byte data]. So accepting this answer would help others with similar issue to try implementing for their own requirement. I will soon post the sample for what I will achieved using apsrc.

Answer (score 0):

You could [write a source element](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/plugin-development/element-types/base-classes.html#writing-a-source), deriving from BaseSrc.

Comment: Thanks @micha137, there are a lot of theory to be understood by reading. So lemme go through the BaseSrc for details.

Comment: I am really not sure if writing to source pad is the appropriate answer or not (again, may be due to my lack of Gstreamer expertise). I was bit bothered/confused reading below 2 lines in the document [That made me not to go further :) ]:1. GStreamer provides two base classes: GstBaseSrc for the basic source functionality, and GstPushSrc , which is a non-byte exact source base-class.  2. The GstBaseSrc may not be suitable for all cases, though; it has limitations: